# Error: Invalid URI while requesting API in nodejs

Tags: javascript, api, openweathermap

Hi I'am new in web programming and I want to practice some API usage by javascript.
I tried to request basic openwatcher API call:

> API call:
>
> ```
> api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name}
> ```

example:

```
var request = require('request');
request("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London",function(error,response,body){
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        console.log(body)
    }
    else{
        console.log(error);
        console.log(response.statusCode)
    }
})
```

But it outputs an error

> Error: Invalid URI "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London"

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) requires that you specify the protocol in the URL.
If you prefix your URL with `http://` (or, ideally, `https://` if supported by the service), it should start working.

Comment: Did as you said and now it just returns status code 401

Comment: Code 401 means that the request is working, but that you aren't permitted to access the resource without correct authentication. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status. api.openweathermap.org requires an API key, as seen on https://openweathermap.org/appid.